# QGIS 3.26 - No option to export to ESRI SHP

Tags: qgis, shapefile, export, mapserver

Option does not exist to export MapServer Layer to SHP in the Export>Save As menu. I've seen this option everywhere in YouTube Videos and other instructions but not in my experience with QGIS. I've scoured the plugins to see if it was hidden but no luck there either.

Comment: Please add a link to at least one such YouTube video. Maybe you have understood something wrong in the video. What do you mean by MapServer layer? If it means a WMS layer, then is contains raster data that cannot be saved as shapefile. And what do you mean by MapServer? This one https://mapserver.org/ or a service from some ESRI server https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190958/what-is-esri-arcgis-mapserver?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 1):

A mapserver layer is (probably) a WMS layer which is a picture of the data and so can't be exported as a vector format like Shapefile (which is obsolete and should be avoided in any case).